Why the notification "table not found" by editing Spring entity?
I work with Spring and got the entity below
package be.simonwyns.webapplicatie.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Goal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Game game;
    @ManyToOne
    private Player scorer;
    @ManyToOne
    private Player assistant;



    public Goal() {
    }

    public Goal(Game game, Player scorer, Player assistant) {
        this.game = game;
        this.scorer = scorer;
        this.assistant = assistant;
    }
    public Goal(Game game, Player scorer) {
        this.game = game;
        this.scorer = scorer;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }
and all the other constructors of course
   
}


I also wanted to add the minute that the goal is scored so I added:
    private int minute;
 public Goal(Game game, Player scorer, Player assistant, int minute) {
        this.game = game;
        this.scorer = scorer;
        this.assistant = assistant;
        this.minute = minute;
    }

and getter and setter:
  public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    public void setMinute(int minute) {
        this.minute = minute;
    }

But now when I reload the application I get the errer that the table Goal is not found. Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "GOAL" not found; SQL statement:
How is this possible by just adding one extra column to the table?

Well this should not occur but as in general
JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException came just like an  exception in SQL query
, one reason i can think of is in your application properties
check if
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
is none , if it is none then Tables will not created into Database.
make it create (this will truncate data everytime you reload the application)
or update

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
